# How to save current location coordinates in google maps on android studio

Tags: android

I have create a simple Google Map Integration on my app. What I am trying to do is to save the user's current location on something that I can access later on, can anyone help me? Maybe some idea or anything that would help.

I already did my research and found nothing.

Comment: `I already did my research and found nothing.` are you saying that you found no [resources related to storing data on android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Google PlacesApi

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/current-place

All the information should be found there. You will need to ask the user's permission to get their current place.

If you need just an approximate location, you can use an api like this one, which uses the IP address to localize the user:

https://ip-api.com/

PS. If the answer has helped you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark!